# How to wait for a value by using Await

Tags: flutter

I'm using Flutter to upload an image to Firebase and have a function submit() that is triggered when I submit the form. On submission, I validate that the submission is accurate and I call the uploadFile function to upload the designated image to Firebase storage and return the URL, which I set to urlForPost.

I want to wait for this urlForPost value to be set before triggering the remainder of the submit() function that uploads this to Firebase. Currently, it is returning a null value for urlForPost. How do I wait for the uploadFile() function to load so that I can prevent urlForPost from being null?

```
void submit() async {
    // First validate form.
    if (this._formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();// Save our form now.

      final urlForPost = await uploadFile();


      Firestore.instance
          .collection('posts')
          .document(documentName)
          .collection('collection')
          .add({
        'user': widget.userPoster,
        'post': _data.post,
        'url': urlForPost,
        'timePosted': Timestamp.now(),
      });

      Firestore.instance.collection('current_goals').document(widget.userPoster).collection(widget.goalType).document(widget.goalID).updateData(
        {
          'complete': true,
        }
      );


      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Home()));    }
  }
  String downloadUrl;

  Future<String> uploadFile() async {

    final String rand1 = "${new Random().nextInt(10000)}";
    final String rand2 = "${new Random().nextInt(10000)}";
    final String rand3 = "${new Random().nextInt(10000)}";
    final StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('${rand1}_${rand2}_${rand3}.jpg');
     await ref.putFile(widget.selectedImage).onComplete.then((val) {
      val.ref.getDownloadURL().then((val) {
        print(val);
        downloadUrl = val; //Val here is Already String
      });
    });

     return downloadUrl;

  }
```

Comment: put the remainder of your submit function after: downloadUrl = val;

Comment: ok, then enjoy the world of async!

Answer (score 0):

You could change your `uploadFile` method to `await` for the upload as well.

You use `await` to make an asynchronous call synchronous. However, if you mix it with `.then()` methods, you're likely to make parts of it unintentionally asynchronous.

```dart
  Future<String> uploadFile() async {
    final String rand1 = "${new Random().nextInt(10000)}";
    final String rand2 = "${new Random().nextInt(10000)}";
    final String rand3 = "${new Random().nextInt(10000)}";

    // you don't need {} if it's a simple statement, use $stringvar and ${value.toString}
    final StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('$rand1_$rand2_$rand3.jpg');

    StorageUploadTask task = ref.putFile(imageFile);
    var downloadUrl = await (await task.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
    debugPrint("downloadUrl=$downloadUrl");
    return downloadUrl.toString();
  }
```

#### just a suggestion unrelated to your original question

Using 3 random numbers, you're likely to have a collision over time. Consider using the [UUID package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/uuid), the chances of collision are dramatically smaller. :)

```dart
  Future<String> uploadFile() async {
    final String uuid = uuid.v4(); // v4 is random, v1 is time-based

    final StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('$uuid.jpg');

    StorageUploadTask task = ref.putFile(imageFile);
    var downloadUrl = await (await task.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();

    return downloadUrl.toString();
  }
```